# css layout not working in different screens?

Tags: php, css

I want to make a website adjust the height and width to fit any screen, I mean it has to change the size by the screen size. I made this code and it looked perfect on my pc but when I opened my website on my work pc which has smaller screen I saw every thing in the website is not in its correct place I mean its messed up.

code:

```
  <html>
    <head><title>overview</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
    </head>
            <body>
               <?php
                  @session_start();
                 if(isset($_SESSION ['id'])) {
                    print ("
                     <div id='nav'><a href='logout.php'>logout</a></div>
                     <iframe src='mainpage.php' name='sidemenu' id='mp'></iframe>
                     <iframe src='sidemenu.php' name='mainpage' id='sm'></iframe>
                     <footer style='background: #4276A4;height: 38px;border: none;'</footer>
                    ");
                  } else { echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0,login.php'>";}
               ?>
            </body>
  </html>
```

css code:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: "JF Flat Regular";
        src: url('fonts/JF/JF-Flat-regular.eot');
        src: url('fonts/JF/JF-Flat-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/JF/JF-Flat-regular.svg#JF Flat Regular') format('svg'),
        url('fonts/JF/JF-Flat-regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/JF/JF-Flat-regular.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    #cmessage {
    display:none;
    }
    #sr,#nw {
    text-decoration:none;
    }

    .si {
    background: #4276A4;
    color: #D9D9D9;
    font-size: 14px;
    float: right;
    font-weight: 900;
    padding: 12px;
    width: 239px;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    font-family: "JF Flat Regular";
    }

    #b {

    background: #4276A4;

    }

    .st {

    background: #4276A4;
    color: #D9D9D9;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: right;
    font-weight: 900;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 239px;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "JF Flat Regular";
    display:none;

    }

    .si:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);


    }
    .st:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);


    }

    #om {

    display:none;
    float: right;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 239px;
    text-align: right;

    }

    #home {

    background: #4276A4;
    color: #D9D9D9;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: right;
    font-weight: 900;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 239px;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "JF Flat Regular";
    }





    #nav { 

    width: 100%;
    height: 38px;
    background: #2D5F8B;
    box-shadow: -10px 0px 20px -15px black;

    }
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #mp {

    height:92.3%;
    width:86.5%;
    border:2px dashed black;
    border-right:none;
    border-bottom:none;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    border-top:none;

    }
    #sm {

    float:right;
    height:95.5%;
    width:13.4%;

    border:none;
    z-index:100;position:absolute;

    }
    .img {

    height: 15px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    }
    #login {
      position: absolute;
      top: 30%;
      left: 50%;
              width: 360px;
      height: 340px;
      margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
    background:rgba(66, 118, 164, 0.69);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    }
    .linput {

    width: 300px;
    height: 31;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: "JF Flat Regular";
    padding-right: 30px;
    border:none;
    margin-left: 30px;
    }
    .sinput {

    width: 300px;
    height: 31;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: "JF Flat Regular";
    padding-right: 30px;
    border:none;
    margin-left: 30px;
    }

    #form {

    margin-top: 65px;


    }
    .lbutton {

    width:132px;
    height:35px;
    background-color:rgba(75, 141, 248, 0.85);
    border:none;
    color:white;
    font-family: "JF Flat Regular";
    margin-left: 121px;
            margin-top: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    }
    .lbutton:hover {
    background-color:rgba(75, 141, 248, 0.31);


    }
    .limg {

    height: 15px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    margin-left: -25px;

    }
    #loginp {

    font-family: "JF Flat Regular";
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.93);
    margin-top: 29px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 135px;

    }
    #hrlogin {
    margin-top: 61px;
    color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    }
            #new {
    font-family: "JF Flat Regular";
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left: 225px;
    }
    #nhref {
    font-family: "JF Flat Regular";
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: -41px;
    margin-left: 125px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 12px;

    }
    #lger {
    font-family: "JF Flat Regular";
    color: #FFF;
    margin-left: 907px;
    margin-top: 100px;


    }
    #signup {
    display:none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 30%;
      left: 50%;
      width: 360px;
      height: 340px;
      margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
    background:rgba(66, 118, 164, 0.69);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    border:none;
    }
    #back {

    display:none;

    }
    #bb { 


    }
    #ibar {


    background-color: #E1D3D3;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: "JF Flat Regular";
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    }
    .orderform {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 34px;
        padding: 3px 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.42857;
        color: #555;
        background-color: #FFF;
        background-image: none;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
        transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
    font-family: "JF Flat Regular";
    }

    .orderform:focus {

    border-color: #999;
    outline: 0px none;
    box-shadow: none;

    }
```

Comment: Consider using Bootstrap for responsive websites, also, I think you made a mistake here: src='mainpage.php' name='sidemenu' id='mp'. I guess the name would be mainpage instead of sidemenu, and in sidemenu likewise.

Comment: @User8889 I will try the bootstrap, src='mainpage.php' name='sidemenu' id='mp' its tfor opening the content inside the other frame in the same page :)

Comment: Adapting to width OK. Adapting to height? If you aren't designing a game or some fancy background covering exactly the screen (*à la one-page-layout*) then just ignore height and let the user scroll, zoom, whatever and the content flow. A web page isn't a PDF (a paged medium)

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to add comment. So answering it.

You have not made your style to be responsive. Define styles for different screen sizes.

For Ex:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) and (max-height:768px) { //for screen with max-width 1024px apply this style

    .banner {
       width:100px;
       height:150px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 880px) {//for screen with max-width 880px apply this style   
    .banner {
       width: 60px;
       height: 90px;
     }
}
```

In the above code different styles are applied to 'banner' class depending on the screensize.

or use Bootstrap for responsiveness as suggested by @User8889.

Comment: your braces do not match up

Comment: This is not an answer, just because you can't comment isn't a reason you should put it as an answer.